# Why is the traceback not stored in the exception object in Python 2?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, exception

From what I understand, in Python 2, if I handle an exception, capture it as an object, and want to do something with the traceback as a string:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    tb = get_traceback(e)
    store_in_database(tb)
```

there is no `get_traceback` function that takes `e` as an argument. There is `import traceback; traceback.format_exc()`, but this doesn't take `e` as an argument. That seems to imply that this information isn't stored in `e` at all.

But in Python > `3.2`, the exception object will have a `__traceback__` attribute which stores the traceback.

I'm interested in knowing:

- At a lower level, where is this information stored? (I know this may be an implementation detail).
- Why was it not stored in `e` up until Python 3?

Comment: You might want to read [PEP-3134](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At a lower level, where is this information stored? (I know this may be an implementation detail).

It's [`sys.exc_info()[2]`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info). This is not an implementation detail.

If you want the implementation details, `sys.exc_info()` is implemented in [`Python/sysmodule.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/sysmodule.c#l149), and it retrieves the traceback from the `exc_traceback` member of the thread's [`PyThreadState`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock).

> Why was it not stored in `e` up until Python 3?

Historical reasons. Python used to not have exception objects at all; the old way used string objects as exceptions. That was a pretty bad system. When they introduced exception objects, they didn't move all the info from `sys.exc_info` to the exception object immediately.